# signtool.exe set proxy for timestamp

Tags: signtool

I want reach the timestamp server for sign a file with signtool.exe behind a firewall, this is my current command:

```
signtool.exe timestamp /t http://timestamp-server foo.exe
```

has sign tool some feature for set the proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> has sign tool some feature for set the proxy?

I think it is impossible to set the proxy with `signtool.exe`.
See also:
[How to timestamp Authenticode signatures when our proxy requires authentication](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2009/09/29/how-to-timestamp-authenticode-signatures-when-our-proxy-requires-authentication/)